Path with Maximum Probability
I am trying to solve this problem:
Path with Maximum Probability leetcode 1514

You are given an undirected weighted graph of n nodes (0-indexed), represented by an edge list where edges[i] = [a, b] is an undirected edge connecting the nodes a and b with a probability of success of traversing that edge succProb[i].
Given two nodes start and end, find the path with the maximum probability of success to go from start to end and return its success probability.
If there is no path from start to end, return 0. Your answer will be accepted if it differs from the correct answer by at most 1e-5.

My code pass the test case but when I submit, for large data, it is giving wrong answer for one test case with very large node. I am doubting that problem lies in memo but can't think of what might be the issue,
 var maxProbability = function (n, edges, succProb, start_node, end_node) {
       const graph = {}
       for (let i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
         const [a, b] = edges[i]
         if (!graph[a]) graph[a] = {}
         if (!graph[b]) graph[b] = {}
         graph[a][b] = succProb[i]
         graph[b][a] = succProb[i] 
      }

      const probability = (current_node, end_node, memo = {}, visited = {})=>{
          if(current_node == end_node) return 1
          visited[current_node] = true
          if(memo[current_node]) return memo[current_node]
          let result = 0;
          for(const node in graph[current_node]){
             if(!visited[node]){
                 result = Math.max(graph[current_node][node] * probability(node, end_node, memo, visited), result)
             }
         }
          delete visited[current_node]
          memo[current_node] = result
          return memo[current_node]
      }
      return probability(start_node, end_node)
  };

can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong.
My understanding of how memo is working in this code above is:

I am building answer from bottom to up so I am storing that in memo with node as key without storing path in memo.

Think of the problem in a different way. Since the probability of failure is 1 - P(success), you need to find the path with minimal probability of failure. Just run a Dijkstra on your graph, since ( [0,1], * ) is a semiring the Dijkstra algorithm will work.

Thank you @m.raynal I am more interested in knowing where I am doing wrong so I can correct my thinking process. Can you please help me on that.

The issue is that your probability function implicitly depends on the current visited nodes, but that is not memoized as part of the state. Consequently, two different paths of arriving at the same node are treated the same and an incorrect answer can be returned.
This problem can be simply solved by just running Dijkstra's algorithm but with the objective of maximizing the probability of the path to each node.
Sample implementation in C++:
double maxProbability(int n, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& edges, std::vector<double>& succProb, int start_node, int end_node) {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, double>>> adj(n);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < edges.size(); ++i) {
        adj[edges[i][0]].emplace_back(edges[i][1], succProb[i]);
        adj[edges[i][1]].emplace_back(edges[i][0], succProb[i]);
    }
    std::vector<double> best(n);
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<double, int>> pq;
    pq.emplace(best[start_node] = 1, start_node);
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        auto [p, u] = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        if (p == best[u])
            for (auto [v, p2] : adj[u])
                if (p * p2 > best[v])
                    pq.emplace(best[v] = p * p2, v);
    }
    return best[end_node];
}


In memoization I am storing value from bottom. When you said that  probability function implicitly depends on the current visited nodes and I am not storing that as part of state, my thinking process was that since I am not building probability from top but from bottom up, i do not need to store path traced. Do u think I am wrong on thinking that ?

@PravinPoudel It looks like you are doing top down dynamic programming with memoization though, not bottom up tabulation.

@PravinPoudel In any case, just consider that you could have two paths 1->2 and 1->3->2. With your current memoization, it would only look at the current node (2) and return the same answer for 1->3->2 as 1->2, which is clearly not correct behavior.

@Unmitigitated thank you for commenting, I am so sorry for not being able to understand, I thought that since i am building answer from base case to up, on node 2, I am storing Max( 4->2, 1->3->5->2)

@PravinPoudel Consider an example where the optimal node to visit next has already been visited along the current path. That will cause the incorrect value to be memoized. See this in action here. In general, be very careful about not capturing all parts of your state. Especially in graph theory problems, it is nearly never correct to only store the visited state of the current path  ephemerally when dynamic programming is called for. And a solution that requires that as part of the state is almost never intended (and will exceed the time limit).
